# @Path configuration at class level and method level

Tags: web-services, http, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am using `javax.ws.rs.Path` class in my REST class to configure path. It is behaving strange ... My configuration is something like this... This is not actual files, but I have shown a replication to make you understand my configurations.

Class1

```
@Path("/v2")
public class BoxResource {        
   @POST
   @Path("/ie/box")
   public Response createbox(...) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Class2

```
@Path("/v2/ie")
public class BagResource {        
    @POST
    @Path("/bag")
    public Response createbag(...) {
        ...
    }        
}
```

When I make a HTTP request like `/v2/ie/box`, it throws the Server configuration error. But if I change my Class2 like below , it works fine.

```
@Path("/v2/ie/bag")
public class BagResource {            
    @POST
    public Response createbag(...) {

    }
}
```

Why is it like .. Does configuration of @path at class level and method level differs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A request to `/v2/ie/box` is mapped to `Class2` because is has

```
@Path("/v2/ie")
```

as a class annotation.

The longest `Path` wins in this case. `Class1` is never looked at since it has the shorter class annotation `@Path("/v2")`.

Since `Class2` has no method that maps to the remaining `/box`, you will get a `404 Not Found`.

**Recommendation**

1. Use `@Path` annotations *only* on the methods: `@Path("/v2/ie/bag")` and `@Path("/v2/ie/box")` **OR**
2. use *one* resource class with a class annotation of `@Path("/v2/ie")` and method annotations of `@Path("/bag")` and `@Path("/box")`.

**Edit**

See also section "3.7 Matching Requests to Resource Methods" of [the JAX-RS 2.0 spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html).

Comment: After making changes i made class level path ("/v2") both classes , even then it is throwing me the same error

Comment: Please read the spec I've linked in my answer. And please add your *real* code to your question.

Comment: I donot understand the specification... And there are other methods in my box class whose path is like /v2/ow/.. So cannnot make one resource.. Also sorry could add real code.. if you need information I can provide u taht

Comment: Option 2 you recommended is not possible in my scenario.. And option 1 is not working.. it still throws configuration error